# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol when expecting one of the following:

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, syntax-error

It seems ok but am getting exception please correct me.

```
declare
    var_number number;

begin
    var_number := 10;

    if var_number > 100 then
        dbms_output.put_line(var_number||' is greater than 100');
    elseif var_number < 100 then
        dbms_output.put_line(var_number||' is less than 100');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line(var_number||' is equal to 100');
    end if;

end;
```

**Exception :**

```
ORA-06550: line 8, column 8:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VAR_NUMBER" when expecting one of the following:
    := . ( @ % ;
ORA-06550: line 13, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
    if
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The keyword for Oracle PL/SQL is "ELSIF" ( no extra "E"), not ELSEIF (yes, confusing and stupid)

```
declare
    var_number number;
begin
    var_number := 10;
    if var_number > 100 then
       dbms_output.put_line(var_number||' is greater than 100');
    elsif var_number < 100 then
       dbms_output.put_line(var_number||' is less than 100');
    else
       dbms_output.put_line(var_number||' is equal to 100');
    end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

The IF statement has these forms in `PL/SQL`:

```
IF THEN
IF THEN ELSE
IF THEN ELSIF
```

You have used `elseif` which in terms of PL/SQL is wrong. That need to be replaced with `ELSIF`.

So your code should appear like this.

```
    declare
        var_number number;
    begin
        var_number := 10;
        if var_number > 100 then
           dbms_output.put_line(var_number ||' is greater than 100');
--elseif should be replaced with elsif
        elsif var_number < 100 then
           dbms_output.put_line(var_number ||' is less than 100');
        else
           dbms_output.put_line(var_number ||' is equal to 100');
        end if;
    end;
```

Answer (score -7):

```
begin
    var_number := 10;

    if var_number > 100 then
        dbms_output.put_line(var_number||' is greater than 100');
    else if var_number < 100 then
        dbms_output.put_line(var_number||' is less than 100');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line(var_number||' is equal to 100');
    end if;
end if;
```